# Are binary quadratic and linear programs equivalent with the same constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

If we consider the following two problems (1) and (2), are they equivalent? Because the values in $\bf x$ can only be either one or zero, the value of the objective function at the optimum $\bf x^*$ does not seem to change. Plus, since both problems are subjected to the same constraints, can I say that solving (1) also solves (2) or viceversa?

(1)
$$\max {\bf x}^T {\bf c}$$
subject to
$${\bf Ax} = {\bf b},$$
$${\bf x} = \{0, 1\}^M$$

(2)
$$\max {\bf x}^T {\bf \mit diag\{\bf c\} \bf x}$$
subject to
$${\bf Ax} = {\bf b},$$
$${\bf x} = \{0, 1\}^M$$

I would much apprecaite some comments and/or references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

$$x^Tdiag\{c\}x=\sum_{i=1}^M c_ix_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^M c_ix_i=x^Tc$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a formal procedure for proving this equivalence?

Comment: Well, the feasible region is the same and the objective function is the same, hence they are equivalent isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course they are exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I prove this equivalence?

Comment: When $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, $x_i^2 = x_i$.